# ListBox Control: First Row Disappears

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, listbox-control

REPOST from my question yesterday.
Complete code below:
I think the problem is at    .Column = MyArray where I send the values into the Listbox thru    .column instead of    .additem. But i can't figure out how to    .additem an    array.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim n As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_initialize()
n = 0
End Sub

Private Sub FBcv_aDD_Click()
ReDim MyArray(4, n)
Dim i As Long
'============================================
If ListBox_FB.ListIndex = True Then
    MyArray(0, n) = "Cavity Fixing Block"
    MyArray(1, n) = FBcv_L.Value & " x " & FBcv_W.Value & " x " & FBcv_T.Value
    If FBcv_Qty <= 1 Then
        MyArray(2, n) = FBcv_Qty.Value & "pc."
    ElseIf FBcv_Qty > 1 Then
        MyArray(2, n) = FBcv_Qty.Value & "pcs."
    End If
    MyArray(3, n) = FBmat.Value
    MyArray(4, n) = FBcv_uPRICE.Value
n = n + 1
End If
'============================================
With ListBox_FB
    For i = 0 To ListBox_FB.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox_FB.ListIndex = False Then
            .AddItem ListBox_FB.List(i, 0)
            ListBox_FB.List(ListBox_FB.ListCount - 1, 1) = ListBox_FB.List(i, 1)
            ListBox_FB.List(ListBox_FB.ListCount - 1, 2) = ListBox_FB.List(i, 2)
            ListBox_FB.List(ListBox_FB.ListCount - 1, 3) = ListBox_FB.List(i, 3)
            ListBox_FB.List(ListBox_FB.ListCount - 1, 4) = ListBox_FB.List(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i
    .ColumnCount = 5
    .TextAlign = 1
    .Column = MyArray
End With
End Sub
```

Sorry I had to repost this, i messed up with my first question.

Can anyone help me sort this out?
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advanCce.

Comment: I tried the advise of L42 to check the code line by line but i still can't find the where i was wrong.

Comment: ListBox stars at 1